# Linting equality checks of MongoDB ObjectIDs

Tags: typescript, mongodb, eslint, objectid

I've been looking around for a nice way to prevent writing `objectId1 === objectId2` when equality-checking MongoDB ObjectIds. Would be nice to have a linting rule (or TypeScript solution) to enforce this.

The problem:

```
const theObjectIdAsString = "6228ab5bedddb4fb156e1f73";

const objectId = new ObjectId(theObjectIdAsString)
const sameObjectId = new ObjectId(theObjectIdAsString)

// works as expected
objectId.equals(sameObjectId) // true
objectId.toHexString() === sameObjectId.toHexString() // true

// the oh-so-easy-to-make-mistake
objectId === sameObjectId // false
```

Any suggestions?